# Split 3-tier menu into columns

Tags: php, html, multiple-columns

I have a 3-tier menu system in that there are 3 levels such that each top-level menu item has X mid-level items and each mid-level item has Y bottom-level items.

For each top-level item I need to split the mid-level and bottom-level items into 3 columns as equally as possible with the restriction that I cannot split the children of a mid-level item into 2+ columns. If I didn't have to keep all the children of a mid-level item together, making equal columns would be pretty much as simple as diving the total number of children in a top level item by 3. However, since I need to group the children of all mid-level items, this seems to become less trivial.

For example - 3 columns of equal length:

```
| Mid 1       | Mid 2       | Mid 3       |
| -Bottom 1-1 | -Bottom 2-1 | -Bottom 3-1 |
| -Bottom 1-2 | -Bottom 2-2 | -Bottom 3-2 |
| -Bottom 1-3 | -Bottom 2-3 | -Bottom 3-3 |
| -Bottom 1-4 | -Bottom 2-4 | -Bottom 3-4 |
```

And 3 unequal columns:

```
| Mid 1       | Mid 2       | Mid 4       |
| -Bottom 1-1 | -Bottom 2-1 | -Bottom 4-1 |
| -Bottom 1-2 | Mid 3       | -Bottom 4-2 |
| -Bottom 1-3 | -Bottom 3-1 | -Bottom 4-3 |
| -Bottom 1-4 | -Bottom 3-1 |             |
```

I'm not looking for code, I'm just looking for an idea on how to approach this conceptually.

Comment: Can you be more specific about what you're trying to do? Is this something like categorising according to two different variables, e.g. alphabetical and properties? Are you looking for a data structure to hold the different configurations of the menus?

Comment: I thought I was quite clear. I have a data structure of 3 levels (As an array, nested where the children of an element is contained within element[children] and so on). I basically have a design that requires me to split this data into 3 columns without breaking up grouped mid-levels. So I am looking for a way to calculate the optimum way of getting each mid-level item into exactly 3 columns, depending on the number of children they all have. See my examples

Comment: Ah, OK. That wasn't clear from the question. You're looking for an algorithm to calculate the best way to distribute the mid and bottom nodes equally. Do the mid-level nodes have to be in any order?

Comment: Preferably, the order they appear in the dataset, but they can of course be shuffled around for best fit in the dataset, as long as the mid-level items aren't split up

Comment: This problem is known as the 3-partition problem (see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/3-partition_problem), just FYI.

Comment: See the following links for a couple of different ways to solve the problem:

http://leetcode.com/2011/04/the-painters-partition-problem.html
http://leetcode.com/2011/04/the-painters-partition-problem-part-ii.html

Comment: Thanks for the links. I'll check them out.